# Need to load a dynamically generated list of strings from an AJAX call (flask backend)

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, list, flask

I think the title says it all, but basically, here is my flask/python backend.

```
@app.route('/failing_jobs/', methods= ['GET' , 'POST'])
def failing_jobs():

    real_list = generate_failing_jobs() #normal method that will generate a list
    dummy_list = ['jobA', 'jobB', 'jobC']
    return dummy_list
```

Now in my template, I've got a script

```
<!-- necesary j-Query includes above this point-->
<script type= "text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        alert("Before the ajax call");
        $.ajax({
            url : "/failing_jobs/",
            type : "GET",
            success : function(data){
                alert(data);
            }
        });
        alert("After the ajax call");
    });
</script>
```

The middle "alert" statment is never being exectuted (although the two sandwiching it are) and on my backend, I've got

```
"TypeError: 'list' object is not callable"
```

Does anyone know a way that I can just output a list, or do I need to break it apart, or what? How do I load a dynamically generated list via ajax?

Comment: The error doesn't belong to this part of the code you are showing us. If the backend is failing, no HTTP 20x is sent (mostly a 50x) and your successhandler is never called. Suggestion: use $.getJSON() as a shortcut for retrieving JSONformatted data.

Comment: @ThomasJunk, yes it does. I get it when I call "return dummy_list"

Comment: So, if you substitute `dummy_list` with `['jobA', 'jobB', 'jobC']` and delete `real_list = generate_failing_jobs()` the result should be exactly your error message, right?

Comment: Correct. I included "real list" for some context as to what I am doing. I know I am generating the list properly, as a print statement is telling me I am.

Comment: @ThomasJunk, I used flask.jsonify, and I appear to be getting closer. However, the json structure is such that EVERYTHING in the list is assigned to one key.

Comment: You could use https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.dumps to serialize your list.

Comment: You must return a string, a tuple (containing a string with optional status code and headers) or a response. A list is not one of the options here. Use `jsonify()` instead (naming the list).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must return a string, a tuple (containing a string with optional status code and headers) or a response. A list is not one of the options here. Use `jsonify()` instead (naming the list):

```
from flask import jsonify

@app.route('/failing_jobs/', methods= ['GET' , 'POST'])
def failing_jobs():
    real_list = generate_failing_jobs() #normal method that will generate a list
    return jsonify(jobs=real_list)
```

On the jQuery side use:

```
$.ajax({
    url : "/failing_jobs/",
    type : "GET",
    contentType: "application/json",
    success : function(data){
        alert(data.jobs);
    }
});
```

Comment: Once again Martjin, you are without a doubt the best flask programmer I have encountered on this site (I think I was missing "contentType").

Comment: Actually have a question for displaying the info. How would I display each of these jobs in the list as a link on my page? Like, if I only had one string, it would be easy. $("#failing_jobs").html(<ahref= "baseurl/" + data.job> data.job </a>)... Would you know how to do this dynamically for mutliple jobs? I'll keep looking but I figured you would know how to do it.

Comment: You'd loop over the list; jQuery has wonderful tools to loop over lists and create new tags from that; a quick Google on 'JSON list to links' gives you loads of Stack Overflow answers; jQuery is not my strongest point so I'll just refer you to that.